# Check if hdd is active or not within program

Tags: c, linux, banana-pi

I would like to check if my hard drive is active or not and set a variable or boolean to use later in the program. I have hdparm installed and working properly to spin down the drive after a set period of time. The drive is on /dev/sda2 and automounts at boot.

I read about `popen()` but am still not great with parsing outputs in c. Is there another way to do this?

Alternatively checking if it is in standby mode will work also.

Comment: When  you say "active" do you mean "not in a power-saving mode?"  Or do you mean "servicing read or write requests?"

Comment: I mean servicing request. Alternatively I could set the boolean if it is in standby mode if that helps.

Comment: @EthanMorris Pick one -- the answers will be significantly different. Also, why do you need to know?

Comment: Trying to learn more about c and programming my banana pro with the wiringpi library. Id like to check this condition and light an led as a hdd status indicator through the gpio pins.

Answer (score 1):

You can just read from "/sys/block/sda2/stat". For documentation see  https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/block/stat.txt.
You program should work like this:

1. Open "/sys/block/sda2/stat" with fopen
2. Use sscanf to parse field 3 (read sectors) and field 7 (write sectors).
3. fclose the file
4. wait for few seconds
5. Repeat steps 1-3. If you got different numbers, the disk was active during that time.

Comment: I don't have sda2 at all but after checking sda/stat and spinning up the drive I do see a difference. All of the read values went up but remain unchanged after the drive went back into standby.